# Calculating the Dini Derivatives of a specific function $f$ (that $f'$ IS NOT lebesgue integrable).

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives

I'm posting this because I need someone to help me understand if I'm thinking in the right way the Dini Derivatives. The exercise is:

> Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a function such that
>   $$
> f(x)=
> \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
> x^2\sin(\pi/x^2), &\textrm{ if }0<x\leq 1 \\
> 0&\textrm{ if }x=0
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>   Show that $f'(x)$ exists for any $x\in[0,1]$ and show that $f'(x)$ IS NOT Lebesgue integrable em $[0,1]$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

$$
\begin{array}{llll}
         D^+f(0)=\lim\sup_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^+}&\{h\sin(\pi/h^2)&:& h\in(0,\varepsilon)\}=0\\
         D_+f(0)=\lim\inf_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^+}&\{h\sin(\pi/h^2)&:& h\in(0,\varepsilon)\}=0\\
         D^-f(0)=\lim\sup_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^+}&\{h\sin(\pi/h^2)&: &h\in(-\varepsilon,0)\}=0\\
         D_-f(0)=\lim\inf_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^+}&\{h\sin(\pi/h^2)&: &h\in(-\varepsilon,0)\}=0
\end{array}
$$
I'll try explain what I think to get it:

$$\lim\sup_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0^+} \{h\sin(\pi/h^2): h\in(0,\varepsilon)\}=\inf_{h\geq0}\sup_{x\in(0,h)}x\sin(\pi/x^2)$$
Now I'm confused. Can I think piecewise here? If yes, i think that:

$\sup_{x\in(0,h)}\{x\sin(\pi/x^2)\}=h$ because, $\sin(\pi/x^2)\leq1$, and $\inf_{h\geq0}\{h\}=0$.

I apply this for all the derivatives to obtain that the derivative exists in $0$. (and in the all the set by the continuity of $f$ in $(0,1]$. This is ok? I'm thinking the right way?

Comment: I don't see why you use Dini derivatives at all. The fact that $\lim_{x\to 0} h \sin(\pi/h^2) = 0$ follows simply from the fact that $|h \sin(\pi/h^2)| \le |h|$. Just apply the definition of limit.